# Tail recursive reading of file OCaml

Tags: exception, ocaml, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

I write a function that print all contents of file like that

```
let rec print_file channel =
    try
    begin
        print_endline (input_line channel);
        print_file channel
    end
    with End_of_file -> ()
```

And because of print_file is last operation I was thinking that it will be optimized to regular loop. but when I had runned my program on really big file, I had got stack overflow.
So I has tried to wrap input_line function to input_line_opt that don't raise exception and little change code of print_file.

```
let input_line_opt channel = 
    try Some (input_line channel)
    with End_of_file -> None

let rec print_file channel =
    let line = input_line_opt channel in
    match line with
        Some line -> (print_endline line; print_file channel)
        | None -> ()
```

And now it works like regular tail recursive function and don't overflow my stack.
What difference between this two function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, `try ... with` is an operation that occurs after the recursive call to `print_file`. So the function is not tail recursive.

You can imagine that `try` sets up some data on the stack, and `with` removes the data from the stack. Since you remove the data after the recursive call, the stack gets deeper and deeper.

This was a consistent problem in earlier revisions of OCaml. It was tricky to write tail-recursive code for processing a file. In recent revisions you can use an `exception` clause of `match` to get a tail position for the recursive call:

```
let rec print_file channel =
    match input_line channel with
    | line -> print_endline line; print_file channel
    | exception End_of_file -> ()
```